# Splash Screen while onCreate ends

Tags: android, splash-screen

My app has 2 activities. The first one is for login, the second one is started when the login of the first one succeded. Since the second activity has to save on a db all my Facebook friends and put them in a certain order inside some list view, I get a black screen passing from the first activity to the second.... What can i do? Is it correctto put a Spalsh Screen between them? IF so, how can I stop the SplashScreen when the on create of the second activity has finished?
Thank you very much

Comment: May be something like this - render the splash screen. Inside call an asynchronous task. When the task is finished return and call another activity.

Answer (score 0):

No using a Splash screen for that won't be a good idea. A better approach would be to have an `AsyncTask`. In `onPreExecute()` method start a progress bar, do all you time consuming code inside your `doInBackground()` method and inside `onPostExecute()` method just dismiss the progress bar and start your Second activity through `Intent`.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Start your progress bar here
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Do all the time consuming code here
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss your progress bar here
    // Start your Second activity
    }

}.execute();
```

Comment: Inside odInBackground should i put the code for filling the db that I do in the second activity so?

@AndroidWarrior

Comment: @JackLametta Yes put all your db code inside `doInBackground()`, it'll show a `ProgressBar` until `doInBackground()` execution is done.